# How can I use 'torch.utils.mobile_optimizer' in PyTorch 1.6.0?

Tags: pytorch

According to https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/mobile_optimizer.html (currently for 1.6.0)

> Torch mobile supports torch.mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile utility to run a list of optimization pass with modules in eval mode. The method takes the following parameters: a torch.jit.ScriptModule object, a blacklisting optimization set and a preserved method list

The page title and

> ```
> torch.utils.mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile(script_module, optimization_blacklist: Set[torch._C.MobileOptimizerType] = None)
> ```

at the end suggest it should be `torch.utils.mobile_optimizer` instead. However, neither work for me:

```
In [25]: module1 = torch.utils.mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile(module)                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-79e42fe53cdf> in <module>
----> 1 module1 = torch.utils.mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile(module)

AttributeError: module 'torch.utils' has no attribute 'mobile_optimizer'

In [26]: module1 = torch.mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile(module)                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-469dd450df3d> in <module>
----> 1 module1 = torch.mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile(module)

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'mobile_optimizer'

In [27]: print(torch.__version__)                                                                                                                          
1.6.0
```

Am I missing anything? E.g. do I have to install some package other than `torch` itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch.utils.mobile_optimizer as mobile_optimizer
scripted_model = torch.jit.script(model, pt_inputs)
opt_model = mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile(scripted_model)
torch.jit.save(opt_model, "model.pt")
```

It works for me